# Activemq subscribing multiple topics

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I have been trying to subscribe to multiple topics from a tcp server using activemq and java.

From what google can tell me, I could either use wildcard or composite destinations to do this Yet the topics are named in the way very unfriendly for wildcard. When I try to set up the destination as "topic1, topic2", I keep receiving errors saying that I am not authorized to these topics while the subscription works smoothly if I just listen to topic1 or topic2 alone.

Some also suggest that I could change the activemq.xml file to set up a broker in there but I do not understand how these works. If this is the solution maybe some one could spare their precious time to explain it to me?

Thanks for your time.

Best regards

To be more specific the code is attached here:

```
import javax.jms.*;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;

public class Consumer {
 // URL of the JMS server
 private static String url = "tcp://datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk:61619";
 private static String username = "my username";
 private static String password = "my password";
 private static String topic = "topic1";

 public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
  BasicConfigurator.configure();
  // Getting JMS connection from the server
  ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
  Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(username,password);
   connection.start();
  Session session = connection.createSession(false,
    Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
  Destination destination = session.createTopic(topic);

  MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);

    while (true)
    {
        //System.out.println("Waiting for message...");
        Message message = consumer.receive();
        if (message != null && message instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage txtMsg = (TextMessage)message;
            System.out.println("Received: " + txtMsg.getText());
        }
    }
    //System.out.println("Closing connection");
    //consumer.close();
    //session.close();
    //connection.close();

}}
```

Comment: What do you mean, you want to subscribe to topics from a tcp server? With an ActiveMQ-JMS-client, you can only subscribe to ActiveMQ-JMS-brokers, please clarify.

Comment: What I did is set up an activemqconnection factory and set the url to the tcp address and topic I am listening to. My problem is that I can only listen to one topic currently while I would need to listen to multiple ones. Hope I have clarified the question. Thanks.

Comment: It would definitely help to see code. If you can listen to one topic, you should have a Session object. Use this to create consumers for other topics.

Comment: I have attached the code in the post, hope that explains the problem. Though not optimal, I found replacing the 'topic1' with '*' do allow me to subscribe to all topics, I am still interested in learning how to subscribe to exact topics I need.

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35715767/jms-consume-multiple-topics for better explanation along with a code example.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do

```
Destination your-second-destination = session.createTopic("name-of-the-second-topic");
MessageConsumer consumer2 = session.createConsumer(your-second-destination);
```

And then have your main class implement the MessageListener interface, and set this as the message listener on both your consumers (it's better than busy-waiting anyway).

On a final note: your are NOT connecting to a TCP server, you're connecting to an ActiveMQ broker via TCP. It might seem picky, but being clear with your words avoids confusion.

Comment: I am not quite sure how to implement the MessageListener interface in the main class, and set this as the message listener on both of the consumers. Very sorry about this but I am just starting to learn Java. Could you please give me an example or a link about this? Thank you very much!

Comment: You are learning Java and start with JMS/ActiveMQ? Well, that's a jump.
You use public class Consumer implement MessageListener {... (your IDE should tell you that you need to implement a method, do so). Then instead of your while(true) loop, just use consumer.setMessageListener(this).

Comment: Well, the only reason I am learning java is that I need to subscribe to this server and run some analysis to the message it is sending, so I just need to get this exact code working. I guess I could try to google the 'public class consumer' that you are mentioning and hopefully I could get it working.

Comment: I'm sorry but you are aware that the "public class Consumer" is your code? It seems that you don't know about object oriented principles, and this is definitely the wrong place to explain them.

Comment: I am sorry but it seems I gave you the wrong impression about my knowledge there. Of course I know that the public class is my code and as a matter of fact I have implemented the MessageListener in my code to replace the while loop. Still, thanks for your help sincerely!